# Overriding execution commands not working to run python scripts through AWS Lambda console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Dockerfile with some packages and lambda_function.py file and it is executed successfully when i tested from AWS Lambda console.
Trying to override the commands through console to run different function in the same python file and i am getting the following error.

> /var/lang/bin/python: can't open file '/var/task/lambda_function.handler': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 69.23 ms Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
>
> Entrypoint - /var/lang/bin/python, CMD override - lambda_function.handler, WORKDIR override - /var/task.

My dockerfile:

```
#FROM python:3.10
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Allow stdout and stderr from Python to be unbuffered
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV LOG_DIR=/tmp

# Copy the local folder to the Docker image
RUN mkdir -p /opt
COPY . /opt

ADD lambda_function.py .

# Set the working directory to the newly created folder
WORKDIR /opt

RUN chmod -R 765 /var/task

CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

my Lambda_function.py:

```
import subprocess

def handler(event, context):
try:
    subprocess.call(["sh","/opt/aaaaa.sh"])
    return 'executed successfully'
except:
    return 'Job failed'
def handler1(event, context):
try:
    subprocess.call(["sh","/opt/sssss.sh"])
    return ' executed successfully'
except:
    return 'Job failed'
```